# How can the performance of an Alloy model be improved?

Tags: performance, alloy

I've written two Alloy solutions to the "water pouring puzzle" (Given a 5 quart jug, a 3 quart jug, can you measure exactly 4 quarts?)

My first attempt (specific.als) hardcodes the two jugs as named relations:

```
sig State {
  threeJug: one Int, 
  fiveJug: one Int 
}
```

It solves the puzzle (finds a counterexample) in about 500ms.

My second attempt (generic.als) is coded to allow for an arbitrary number of jugs and different sizes:

```
sig State {
  jugAmounts: Jug -> one Int
}
```

It solves the puzzle in about 2000ms.

Is it possible for the generic code, to run as quickly as the specific code?
What would need to be changed?

## Specific Model

```
open util/ordering[State]


sig State {
  threeJug: one Int, 
  fiveJug: one Int 
}


fact {
  all s: State {
    s.threeJug >= 0
    s.threeJug <= 3
    s.fiveJug >= 0
    s.fiveJug <= 5
  }

  first.threeJug = 0
  first.fiveJug = 0
}


pred Fill(s, s': State){
  (s'.threeJug = 3 and s'.fiveJug = s.fiveJug)
  or (s'.fiveJug = 5 and s'.threeJug = s.threeJug)
}


pred Empty(s, s': State){
  (s.threeJug > 0 and s'.threeJug = 0 and s'.fiveJug = s.fiveJug)
  or (s.fiveJug > 0 and s'.fiveJug = 0 and s'.threeJug = s.threeJug)
}


pred Pour3To5(s, s': State){
  some x: Int {
    s'.fiveJug = plus[s.fiveJug, x]
    and s'.threeJug = minus[s.threeJug, x]
    and (s'.fiveJug = 5 or s'.threeJug = 0)
  }
}


pred Pour5To3(s, s': State){
  some x: Int {
    s'.threeJug = plus[s.threeJug, x]
    and s'.fiveJug = minus[s.fiveJug, x]
    and (s'.threeJug = 3 or s'.fiveJug = 0)
  }
}


fact Next {
  all s: State, s': s.next {
    Fill[s, s']
    or Pour3To5[s, s']
    or Pour5To3[s, s']
    or Empty[s, s']
  }
}


assert notOne {
  no s: State | s.fiveJug = 4
}


check notOne for 7
```

## Generic Model

```
open util/ordering[State]


sig Jug {
  max: Int
}


sig State {
  jugAmounts: Jug -> one Int
}


fact jugCapacity {
  all s: State {
    all j: s.jugAmounts.univ {
      j.(s.jugAmounts) >= 0
      and j.(s.jugAmounts) <= j.max
    }
  }

  -- jugs start empty
  first.jugAmounts = Jug -> 0
}


pred fill(s, s': State){
  one j: Jug {
    j.(s'.jugAmounts) = j.max
    all r: Jug - j | r.(s'.jugAmounts) = r.(s.jugAmounts)
  }
}


pred empty(s, s': State){
  one j: Jug {
    j.(s'.jugAmounts) = 0
    all r: Jug - j | r.(s'.jugAmounts) = r.(s.jugAmounts)
  }
}


pred pour(s, s': State){
  some x: Int {
    some from, to: Jug {
      from.(s'.jugAmounts) = 0 or to.(s'.jugAmounts) = to.max
      from.(s'.jugAmounts) = minus[from.(s.jugAmounts), x]
      to.(s'.jugAmounts) = plus[to.(s.jugAmounts), x]
      all r: Jug - from - to | r.(s'.jugAmounts) = r.(s.jugAmounts)
    }
  }
}


fact next {
  all s: State, s': s.next {
    fill[s, s']
    or empty[s, s']
    or pour[s, s']
  }
}


fact SpecifyPuzzle{
  all s: State | #s.jugAmounts = 2
  one j: Jug | j.max = 5
  one j: Jug | j.max = 3
}


assert no4 {
  no s: State | 4 in univ.(s.jugAmounts)
}


check no4 for 7
```

Answer (score 1):

By experience, better performance can be obtained by :

- Reducing the size of the search space ( by decreasing the scope, the number of sig and relations, the arity of relations,..)
- **Simplifying constraints**. Try to avoid using set comprehension and quantification as much as possible. As an example, your assertion,  `no s: State | 4 in univ.(s.jugAmounts)` is logically equivalent to `4 not in univ.(State.jugAmounts)`. Making this tiny change alone in your model has already made the processing of clauses 200ms faster on my end.

**EDIT**

I came back to your problem during my free time.

Here's the model I used to reach this conclusion

```
module WaterJugs/AbstractSyntax/ASM
open util/ordering[State] 
open util/integer


//===== HARDCODE 2 jugs of volume 3 and 5 resp.  comment those lines for generic approach ====
one sig JugA extends Jug{}{
    volume=3
    water[first]=0
}
one sig JugB extends Jug{}{
    volume=5
    water[first]=0
}
//==================================================================

abstract sig Jug{
    volume: Int,
    water:  State  ->one Int
}{
    all s:State| water[s]<=volume and water[s]>=0
    volume >0
}

pred Fill(s1,s2:State){
    one disj j1,j2:Jug{j1.water[s1]!=j1.volume and j1.water[s2]=j1.volume and j2.water[s2]=j2.water[s1] }
}

pred Empty(s1,s2:State){
    one disj j1,j2:Jug{ j1.water[s1]!=0 and  j1.water[s2]=0 and  j2.water[s2]= j2.water[s1] }
}

pred Pour(s1,s2:State){
    one disj j1,j2: Jug{
        add[j1.water[s1],j2.water[s1]] >j1.volume implies {
            ( j1.water[s2]=j1.volume and j2.water[s2]=sub[j2.water[s1],sub[j1.volume,j1.water[s1]]])}
        else{
            ( j1.water[s2]=add[j1.water[s1],j2.water[s1]] and j2.water[s2]=0)
        }
    }
}

fact Next {
  all s: State-last{
    Fill[s, s.next]
    or Pour[s, s.next]
    or Empty[s, s.next]
  }
}

sig State{

}

assert no4 {
  4 not in Jug.water[State]
}

check no4 for 7
```

In bonus, here's a visualization of the counter exemple provided by [Lightning](http://lightning.gforge.uni.lu)

[image: counter exemple visualization]

Comment: I'm not able to detect any performance difference by reducing quantifications like replacing `all s: State | #s.jugAmounts = 2` with `#Jug = 2`, or `no s: State | 4 in univ.(s.jugAmounts)` with `4 not in univ.(State.jugAmounts)`.

It could be that a difference exists, but is difficult to measure due to JVM's just-in-time compiler.

Comment: Interesting, I guess a tangible way to quantify an increase in performance could be to compare the number of clauses generated. The smaller this number, the better.

Comment: I had some time to fiddle with your example and updated the answer with my model. Feel free to reuse it as you please

Comment: Thanks for your follow up --- I'm not familiar with all the syntax in your model, nor have I seen Lightning, and both look worth pursuing.

Sorry if the written explanation of my model wasn't clear. It is definitely possible to get 4 quarts into a jug, that's the whole point of the puzzle! = )

Comment: The syntax in this model is independent from Lightning (it's pure Alloy that can be used with the Alloy Analyzer). If you would like some help to understand some syntactic constructs, do not hesitate :-). Same goes if you are interested in trying out Lightning